# My Fn keys just stop working!

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

Well I have ubuntu 12.04LTS on my laptop. Everything worked fine till last night. But today when I started my system it seems that my gaphic is a little different (lower) and there are something that just stop working like my Fn keys won't work. My volume keys (
mute-lower-higher volume) won't working anymore!!!

What's the problem?

I did not change or update anything. The last time I used my system I was playing a game via Wine.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the game you were playing inside of wine changed the resolution of the desktop which has strangely stayed the same on reboot, reset the screen resolution in settings...  As for the fn keys, that's a strange one as you should still be using the same keyboard language as before but to be sure go into Kayboard Layout and check it's set for your laptop...

Comment: I checked that and nothing was changed about keyboard layout!!!